# How to report a bug in IE Developer Toolbar?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I found a bug in the IE8 developer toolbar.  How do I report it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar [download page](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038&displaylang=en), bugs should be reported on the IE Web Developer forum on MSDN:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/threads/.